# Post array/object with the Request module

Tags: arrays, node.js, object, post, request

I'm trying to make http post request using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module

```
text = 'some data';

request.post('http://example.com/read', {form:{data: text}});
```

This works fine for a simple string, but I need to be able to send an array or object.

When I try to read the array/object in the post handler the data property is empty.

What's going here? Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Post your server side code. Are you using perhaps the connect bodyParser middleware? If so, you want `req.body.form.data` to get at your text.

Comment: yes am using connect bodyParser middleware. I was only doing console.log(req.body) which gave me empty object but  with req.body.form.data I get 'property data undefined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
var request = require('request');

request({
  method: 'POST',
  uri: 'http://example.com/read',
  body: {'msg': 'secret'},
  json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('code: '+ response.statusCode);
  console.log(body);
})
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Yep. Perfect. I never wanted to use form anyway, just thought it was necessary. Thanks